# Heroku thinks I'm using bootstrap? Won't let me rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I was originally using bootstrap for a bit of prototyping but then I removed it. Now, I'm trying to push to Heroku, but keep getting this error:

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
   Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/tmp/build_1xogapzflu9oq/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
   (in /tmp/build_1xogapzflu9oq/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
```

Of course it's unreadable because I removed bootstrap. Why is it still looking for it? I deleted everything in tmp, custom.css.scss doesn't even exist in my stylesheets, and there's no mention of bootsrap anywhere in my app! I've also tried deleted and recreating Heroku app.

What's going on here that I'm missing? Thanks!

**Edit:** `rake assets:clean` did not do anything either before heroku push or after.

Comment: does `git status` show anything? what about `git push heroku master`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `app/assets/stylesheets/custom` & `app/assets/stylesheets/application` files & remove bootstrap's `//=require` directive, if present.

Further, if problem still persists. do the following

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "bootstrap fix"
$ git push heroku master
```

Lastly, if you still get the error. Paste your `app/assets/stylesheets/application` file, so we can debug what's going on

Comment: Yes I've removed the bootstrap require from both of those, and re-pushing didn't help. My current application.css is just `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree .`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bootstrap gem etc, remove it from Gemfile, and put your bootstrap css and js files manually in proper assets folder.